# Will my vent siphon the bathtub P-trap?

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, drain, vent, pvc

We're modifying our bathroom by moving a shower and bathtub around, but we're having trouble working around the limitations of the space. For some background, we're in Florida and are governed by the UPC and IRC, and freezing pipes is not a concern. However, the exterior walls are 2x4 stud walls. The joists are 2x10, 16" O.C.

Here it is as built (but not glued.) This is from below looking up. The waste stack is inside the wall to the right. Everything is 2" PVC except for the vent (in blue), which is 1-1/2" PVC.
[image: Detail of drain and vent for bathtub and shower, looking up from below]

Here's an isometric render of the room with the plumbing diagram. I added a blue line to show another vent that we *could* connect to if we had to. These are the plans I submitted to the permit office, which they approved.

[image: Isometric view of room and plumbing]

I have two main concerns:

- There's a long horizontal branch vent run that is well below the flood rim of the bathtub. There's not really a good way around this, though. However, the vent connects to a larger vent stack in the attic well above the flood rim. I don't know how to interpret the code here to determine if this is okay, but I can't really find any pictures on Google that look like our situation.
- The top of the connection of the drain to the vent is below the top of the weir for the bathtub. We're extremely close to 8' of developed length already, but I'm pretty sure that because of the extra slope at the end, this could cause the P trap to be siphoned. My wife is convinced that the velocity of the water here will never allow the horizontal drain pipe to be full of water, but I'm not sure the inspector will see it that way.

As noted in the second picture, there is another vent stack that serves the two sinks in the bathroom and the kitchen sink and dishwasher below. It's a 2" pipe, so it should have plenty of capacity. However, we would have to drill through at least 3 external wall studs to reach it.

So, how badly did the original builder screw us? Also, why did the permit office approve our plans anyway? They were very particular about code compliance for the electrical portion, but they approved the plumbing on the first try.

Comment: If the length of the tub drain to that point is 8 feet, it's too much. If the length of the total tub drain to *the vent location* is under 8 feet, that part is technically correct. MOST "long low runs of bathroom venting" come under the wet-venting rules, but I'm more familiar with IPC than UPC - but that's where to look. You might be able to move your vent sideways through the joists to avoid as much boring of the exterior wall studs?

Comment: Yeah, the measurement is from the end of the trap to the edge of the vent. It's around 94". Maybe I misunderstood some of the code, though - can a vent be under 6" above flood rim if it's sloped up? I must have been thinking of the rule for a level vent. That addresses one of the two problems, then. Thank you for your help!

Perhaps we could raise the top of the waste stack a little, but I don't know of a good fitting to get the vent connection done right.

Comment: what is developed length?  check the critical arm length here:  https://www.jlconline.com/how-to/plumbing/maximum-length-for-fixture-drains_o.  Are your external wall studs bearing?  You could connect up a 1 1/4" vent to minimize the stud holes.

Comment: Last time I looked in the Uniform Plumbing Code, it required the vent on a 2" drain to be located a maximum of 5 ft from the trap weir, and even closer if the drain has more than the minimum slope.